# "Index was out of range" Exception Thrown in DataGridView SelectionChanged event While FormLoad

Tags: c#, datagridview, selectionchanged

I populated my `DataGridView` which is named `DataSourceGrid` using following code inside `FormLoad`

```
String mquery = "SELECT ProductName,UnitPrice,CategoryName FROM ProductsTable INNER JOIN CategoryTable ON ProductsTable.Categoryid = CategoryTable.Categoryid";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(mquery, con);
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    DataSourceGrid.DataSource = dt;

                }
```

I used the following code to select rows of the `DataGridView` inside `SelectionChanged` event block

```
                int curRow = -1;
                int curColumn = -1;
                curRow = DataSourceGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
                curColumn = DataSourceGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                string firstCellValue = DataSourceGrid.SelectedRows[curRow].Cells[curColumn].Value.ToString();
                if (DataSourceGrid.CurrentRow.Index >= -1)
                {
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                    {

                        String query = "SELECT ProductName,UnitPrice,CategoryName FROM ProductsTable INNER JOIN CategoryTable ON ProductsTable.Categoryid = CategoryTable.Categoryid WHERE ProductName='" + firstCellValue + "'";
                        con.Open();
                        SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader();
                        sdr.Read();
                        ProductNameText.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        UnitPriceText.Text = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        CategoryText.Text = sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();

                    }
```

when I click on a row the data will be displayed in the corresponidng TextBoxes. My problem is when the `FormLoad` an exception is thrown saying `Index was out of range...`[Here is the Exact Exeption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhxQd.png) 
thanks for your support.

Comment: Use break points, then inspect the variables on this line `DataSourceGrid.SelectedRows[curRow].Cells[curColumn]` my spidey senses tell me you will figure out the problem, most likely a `-1`

Comment: On which Line??

Comment: What do you think will happen if `DataSourceGrid.CurrentRow.Index` is -1? (Hint: `curRow` will be -1.) Also, it is possible that `DataSourceGrid.CurrentRow` is null (which would cause a different error).

Comment: @Atk Exception Throws in `DataSourceGrid.SelectedRows[curRow].Cells[curColumn]`

Comment: @MatthewWatson if DataSourceGrid.CurrentRow.Index is -1 I set a Label to Print the Value.

Comment: @MichaelRandall is -1 the there is a label to show its value in `else` Block

Comment: So if `curRow` is -1, what do you think will happen when you try to use it in `string firstCellValue = DataSourceGrid.SelectedRows[curRow].Cells[curColumn].Value.ToString();`? Pay attention to the `SelectedRows[curRow]` part.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
                int curRow = DataSourceGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
                int curColumn = DataSourceGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

                // First check for -1 and then do the rest.
                if (curRow > -1 && curColumn > -1)
                {
                    string firstCellValue = DataSourceGrid.SelectedRows[curRow].Cells[curColumn].Value.ToString();
```

Arrays have indexes from `0` to `Length-1`, so if the index is -1 then it is what the exception says **OutOfIndex**

Another solution would be the following if you want to acces the first element when the values are -1.

```
if (curRow >= -1 && curColumn >= -1)
{
    curRow = curRow == -1 ? 0 : curRow;
    curColumn = curColumn == -1 ? 0 : curColumn;
    string firstCellValue = DataSourceGrid.SelectedRows[curRow].Cells[curColumn].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: didn't work I used `(curRow >= -1 && curColumn >= -1)` instead `(curRow > -1 && curColumn > -1)` so that I can test both condition.

Comment: You must drop the equal as it will enter the if close when the values are -1 which will throw the out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: Check the updated answer. It might solve your problem if I understood it correctly.

Comment: not working bro.Idk whether I missed something to mention in the question